# Keras: how to append a vector to a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, dimensions

I have a network with keras / tf where two branches are built: 
- one where a short sequence of words is transformed into 300-dim embeddings
- the other where the same sequence of words is transformed into ngrams

I then end up with two data structures:

```
termwords.shape = (?, 42, 300)
termngrams.shape = (?, 42)
```

(I make sure that both branches have the same 'length' of 42, ie. maximally 42 words and maximally 42 ngrams, padding/cutting where needed). I'd then need to merge these into one branch to arrive at the prediction layer.

But

```
merged = merge([termwords, termngrams], mode='concat')
```

tells me that the ranks don't match. I was hoping concat would allow me to append the 'termngrams' to the 'termwords' such that I end up just with a data structure of shape (?,42,301). But I can't find the proper way to express that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rank" error is telling you that the tensors don't have the same number of dimensions. One is 2D and the other is 3D.

Use a `Lambda` layer with `expand_dims` to add an extra dimension to the 2D one.

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda

termngrams = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x))(termngrams) #outputs (?,42,1)
```

Then use a [Contatenate()](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate) layer (by default it uses the last axis, as you want).

```
merged = Concatenate()([termwords,termngrams])
```

(Assuming you're using a functional API `Model` instead of sequential models, sequential models aren't good for branching)

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! I had spent quite some time searching, assuming that there must be a simple way to address that, but I had not run into expand_dims. Network not compiles and runs ... will need continue to see how to tune results. Again: Thanks!

Comment: Great :) --- If you consider that this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)